# How do I auto-update Assembly Version in C# but using Semantic Versioning

Tags: c#, msbuild

I know there are plenty of solutions for using the AssemblyInfo task from the MSBuild Extension pack, but the trouble is, AssemblyInfo tasks requires the version to be four places, i.e. 1.2.3.4, whereas Semantic Versioning requires only three, i.e. 1.2.3. If you try and use a three digit version, the AssemblyInfo task throws an error.

As a firm we're moving towards Semantic Versioning and our build scripts aren't happy about it. I was curious if there was perhaps a newer version

Comment: Can you not simply always use "0" for the revision number? Is this compatible with semantic versioning?

Comment: It technically is, but it's not in the spirit of semantic versioning.

Comment: Semantic versioning only requires you to version "packages" that provide an API. They could be anything, including just a collection of specification documents. It does make sense to version executable files, assemblies and particularly installers and nuget packages with similar numbers, though they all have their own schemes and requirements/limitations.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was using old MSBuild Extension pack from CodePlex. I switched the MSBuild Tasks package from Nuget and that version is new and allows the entry of three digit versions. It's also a great place to start if you're thinking about creating an MSBuild file for your solution.

Comment: So you just get a 0 then?